# Selecting different views from a Sharepoint library

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Firstly apologies if this is a basic question. I'm very new to Sharepoint design and do not have access to Sharepoint designer so have to do it all directly in Sharepoint.

I have a number of files and I have created a number of different libraries to house this information. Every library has the same folder structure (ie Year > Month) and I think it'd be better to have it all within one library and use views to filter what I need.

I wanted to create multiple links to this library and each link to show a different view depending on what link is pressed, eg link1 shows view1 and link2 shows view2 etc. But instead of creating a a huge number of views I wanted the user to click a link, select the year and quarter they want and then the view shows just the files specific to that request. I also wanted to add the library as a we part on to the request page and have only the we part refresh when a selection is made.

Is this easily done?

Thanks for any help ppl!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, folders are a pain.  I'd suggest creating one view that groups by year, then month.  Then plant a list view web part and specify the view you just created in the Selected View in the web part properties.